# Invariants of groups that are invariant under passage to finite index subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, model-categories

This question is mostly idle curiosity.

Recall the following standard terminology: if $P$ is a property of groups, a group $G$ is said to be virtually $P$ if it has a subgroup of finite index which is $P$. First, a preparatory question:

> Is there an established name in the literature for invariants of groups which are invariant under passage to finite index subgroups?

For example, I think the quasi-isometry class of a finitely generated group has this property. Somewhat more generally I think the [coarse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarse_structure) equivalence class of a group has this property.

For now let me call such things "virtual invariants." It is tempting to try to study virtual invariants by studying the universal such thing: namely, start with the category of (possibly finitely generated) groups, then localize at the inclusions of finite index subgroups.

> Has anyone computed anything about this localization? In particular, is there a model category structure on (possibly finitely generated) groups with inclusions of finite index subgroups as weak equivalences?

Comment: Apparently if we toss in quotients with finite kernel then the resulting equivalence relation is called weak commensurability. The corresponding question in this case about model structures also seems interesting.

Comment: Just a small comment: there's no model category structure on the category of finitely generated groups. A model structure always requires the category to have all limits and colimits.

Comment: Groups are called abstractly commensurate if they have isomorphic finite index subgroups. This is not the name for the class of invariants though.

Comment: It seems then that Qiaochu's "virtual invariants" are something like $\mathcal O(\{\text{equivalence classes for abstract commensurability}\})$, right?  I have nothing useful to say towards the posted question.

Comment: This question seems related: http://mathoverflow.net/q/97759/1345
In fact, for many classes of groups, such as lattices in semisimple groups, the abstract commensurator contains any member of the commensurability class as a subgroup. However, incommensurable groups can have isomorphic commensurators.